# Cannot access session variables when debug is set to 0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a strange problem where my application runs OK with debug set to 1 or 2 but not 0.

I want to set the prod server to debug 0 (core.php **Configure::write('debug', 0);**).

We have written a security module that authenticates to our ActiveDirectory servers using LDAP.  This is working fine and saves the user details in a session variable, $_SESSION['Security_Details'].

```
private function restoreAuthenticationDetails(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['Security_Details'])){
        $security_details = json_decode($_SESSION['Security_Details']);

        $this->firstName = $security_details->firstName;
        $this->lastName = $security_details->lastName;
        $this->uNumber = $security_details->uNumber;
        $this->systems_management = $security_details->systems_management;
        $this->loggedin = 1;
    }else{
        $this->loggedOut();
    }
}
```

With debug 1 I see $_SESSION['Security_Details'] has these contents:

```
"{"firstName":"Duane","lastName":"Walker","uNumber":"uXXXXXXX"}"
```

but with debug 0 all I get is NULL.

It seems like this is a security feature or is it not intended to behave like this.

How do I enable access to session variables under debug 0?

Comment: I see there is a SessionComponent that I should be using instead.

Comment: Either that, or `CakeSession` in case you're not in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method in creating or reading sessions in CakePHP:

```
  $this->Session->write("my_session", "123"); //how to create a session
  $this->Session->read("my_session"); //will return 123
```